# how do you display multiple message to a text area

Tags: java, message, jtextarea

I want to display multiple messages to the same text area without clearing any of previous messages.

```
double betAmount=100;
messages.setText("you are betting,$"+betAmount+"\n");
messages.setText("you stand\n");
messages.setText("you hit\n");
```

you are betting,$100.0
you stand
you hit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 messages.setText("you are betting,$"+betAmount+"\n");
 messages.append("you stand\n");
 messages.append("you hit\n");
```